# Toggle working, but not animating on Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing Bootstrap 3 on a site, and upgrading from Bootstrap 2.3.

I have a little toggle on the navbar, that used to work like a charm, but now is toggling, but without sliding transition. I checked the Bootstrap 3 upgrading documentation and didn't find anything.

What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-info ico pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#info"><i class="icon-white icon-info-sign"></i></button>
<div class="ix-info-costumer pull-right">
<ul class="ix-down">
<li><strong><?php echo _t('Username')?></strong>: {{userData.firstname}} {{userData.lastname}}</li>
<li><strong><?php echo _t('Credit balance')?></strong>: {{creditData.available | currency: '€'}}</li>
<ul id="info" class="collapse">
<li><strong><?php echo _t('Customer id')?></strong>: {{userData.customerId}}</li>
<li><strong><?php echo _t('Service PIN')?></strong>: {{userData.servicePin}}</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions:

> For simple transition effects, include transition.js once alongside
>   the other JS files. If you're using the compiled (or minified)
>   bootstrap.js, there is no need to include this—it's already there.